# URL of GeoServer Shapefile?

Tags: geoserver, wms, url, localhost

So trying to work through the setup of geoserver and using an example script see below.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var layers = [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
        }),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
          source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states', 'TILED': true},
            serverType: 'geoserver'
          })
        })
      ];
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: layers,
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-10997148, 4569099],
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`

When opening the page though i cannot see the sample shapefiles 'topp:states'
Anyone know what i am doing wrong?

I assume i have something wrong with the URL for the source.

Comment: Is topp:states published in the geoserver/cite/wms endpoint?

Comment: not sure, how would i check? thanks for the reply

Comment: Try to modify the call to your wms layer this way: new ol.layer.Image (instead of Tile), new ol.source.ImageWMS (instead of TileWMS), add  'FORMAT': 'image/png' in the params

Comment: To check you would use a GetCapabilities request, like `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&`

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue.
The URL was wrong instead of it being

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms
```

it should have been

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms
```

Comment: To add a bit of information: Your original URL tried to load topp:states in the cite namespace while it is part of the topp namespace.